How to get Access_Token after successful authentication in Azure AD using OWIN (in Webform)
my Project is developed in Asp.net (webform). By using OWIN i need to implement below 2 requirement

I want to integrate IDP (Azure AD) User Authentication on that project like when the user try to visit our website then first the user will be redirected to IDP login page (Azure AD). There the user will enter his credential and then after successful authentication the user will be redirected to our project home page.

Once the user redirected then in our code we should able to capture the access_token and that access_token we need to pass in the header while calling webservice for loading other functionalities.


For now I am able to achieve 1st requirement but facing issue in implementing 2nd requirement i.e capturing the Access_token on my project after successful authentication in IDP.
So can anybody please help me on this by providing a working example.
I have tried below Code but getting the access_Token as NULL.
Installed the required Nuget Packages.
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Startup.cs file
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = _clientId,
            Authority = _authority,
            RedirectUri = _redirectUri,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            Scope = "openid",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                {

                    var accessToken = context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {

                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType ==OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                    {
                        
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        }
            );
    }

Default.aspx.cs
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
              new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
              OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }            
    }

